# Refresh without jumping to previous scroll/window location in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, scrolling, refresh

I'm trying to figure out how I can refresh a page without jumping to the previous scroll location in Google Chrome. When using Firefox this can be done by pressing Ctrl + F5 to refresh the page, cache and forget the scroll location. With Chrome I tried F5 and Shift + F5 like suggested on multiple places on the internet (to forget cache). However the scroll position is remembered when doing this.

Situation:

> I'm working in a Confluence document and it would be nice if I can
> jump back to the selected location.
>
> Example url:
> https://confluence.example.net/display/space/pagename#anchor
>
> In this case, after scrolling around on the page I would like to jump back to #anchor.

My question is, how do I achieve this?

Comment: This is a big bug of chrome that I can't find a solution for months now. Even if you clear page cache and refresh it will stay on the same position. Either way you can try. press `F12`, right-click the refresh button and choose `Empty cache and hard reload`. Otherwise your best guess is to try an extention

Comment: @D.A Thanks for the response, seems like no other answers are coming in. Development-mode is a bit much for only a hard refresh, I'm going to look into some extensions and post it here if I find something useful.

Comment: I have the same issue - at least I'm not alone... As a workaround, you can change the anchor to something else (e.g. add a '2') and then change it back, which will re-scroll to the selected anchor...

Comment: If this is a bug, is there a bug report somewhere out there?

Comment: This was bugging me for years and I finally tried to find a solution, unfortunately there doesn’t seem to be one. My workaround is always to close the tab and reopen it. So `Ctrl+L`, `Ctrl+C`, `Ctrl+W`, `Ctrl+T` and finally `Ctrl+V` and `Enter`

Comment: I just thought I’d add my comment as an answer since it’s at least a workaround and solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

When closing the tab is an option then there is a workaround. I guess it’s an option because with a reload you would lose all entered text anyways and I can’t think of another reason why you wouldn’t want to close the tab. It’s just a problem if this is your last opened tab in this window as Chrome will close the window if the last tab is closed.

My workaround is always to close the tab and reopen it. So <kbd>Ctrl+L</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+T</kbd> and finally <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Interestingly, there’s [this Chromium bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=567218) and the [pasted URL there](https://music.utoronto.ca/orientation.php#Tours) works (click on link, scroll a bit and do a normal reload with <kbd>F5</kbd> and you get back to `#Tours`). However, I just tested it with Wikipedia and it doesn’t work there.

Comment: This works, but wasn't really what I was hoping for. Also be careful not to use Ctrl+W if your current tab is the only one. Still +1 from me though.

Comment: Yeah, I already wrote that in my answer about the last tab :)